# Custom Servlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I have created some custom servlets, and invoke it like:

https://[domain]/delegate/getpefrentry?param1=blabla&param2=sdsada

It works fine, but if I restart the server, I get this error:

> The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception**
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: No servlet registred for context getpefrentry
>       com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegatorServlet.service(PortalDelegatorServlet.java:79)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
>       com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
>       com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:208)
> ```

I need to hot deploy the war file of the servlet to make it work again.

My Liferay-hook.xml:

```
<hook>
<portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
<language-properties>content/Tips.properties</language-properties>
<servlet-filter>
    <servlet-filter-name>MyFilter</servlet-filter-name>
    <servlet-filter-impl>com.ncs.phm.ws.PhmWebServiceFilter</servlet-filter-impl>
</servlet-filter>
<servlet-filter-mapping>
    <servlet-filter-name>MyFilter</servlet-filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/delegate/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</servlet-filter-mapping>
```

my web.xml:

`<servlet>
<display-name>WSPEFR</display-name>
<servlet-name>WSPEFR</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
  <param-value>com.ncs.phm.ws.PhmWebServicePefr</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
  <param-value>getpefrentry</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>method</param-name>
  <param-value>get-latest-pefr-entry</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>`

I also added in portal.properties this:
auth.public.paths=/delegate/*

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the below code in com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegatorServlet's service().

```
String[] paths = uri.split(StringPool.SLASH);
HttpServlet delegate = _delegates.get(paths[1]);
if (delegate == null) {
     throw new ServletException("No servlet registred for context " + paths[1]);
}
```

Where it's expecting the second string in the uri should be present in the delegates list. ex: /delegate/servlet-name

Did you register your portal delegator in the init() PortalDelegateServlet?. If not try with this.
It ensures, the delegate is added once the servlet is loaded by the servlet container.

```
servlet.init(config);
PortalServletDelegationManager.addDelegate(subContext, servlet);
```

Let me know the outcome of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried, but it's still the same.. I put a log on the PortalDelegateServlet,  it only comes out if I hot deploy. If I restart it seems it's not being loaded, thus still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue is this line in your `liferay-hook.xml`:

```
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
```

(`0` meaning `false`)

Change it to `1` to load your servlet on startup.